# How to find a solution to the modular equation $23\cdot 34^x+29\equiv N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$23\cdot 34^x+29 \equiv N \pmod {559}$.
I am seeking for values of N satisfayng the above modular equation such that $x\equiv 2\pmod {84}$. Is there a general method to solve it? Does every even number $N\equiv 10^m \pmod {41}$ for some m satisfy that modular equation with $x\equiv 2\pmod {84}$? Does every $N\equiv 344 \pmod {559}$ satisfy the above equation?

Comment: Do you know Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Yes I know CRT sure

Comment: First , you need the order of $34$ modulo $559$ (the smallest positive integer $k$ satisfying $$34^k\equiv 1\mod 559$$) which is $84$ in this case. Then, you only have to check the values $1-84$ to find all solutions modulo $84$

Comment: @Peter you see that exponents of ec primes multiple of 86 that is 69660, 92020 and 541456 satisfy this modular equation with x congruent to 2 mod 84

Comment: Since $34^{84}\equiv 1 \pmod {559}$ we have,  $x\equiv 2 \pmod {84}\implies 34^x\equiv 34^2\equiv 38\pmod {559}$, so $N$ is determined uniquely, $\pmod {559}$.

Comment: @lulu every number $N\equiv 344 \pmod {559} $ satisfies the equation?

Comment: @Peter  every number $N\equiv 344 \pmod {559} $ satisfies the equation?

Comment: Yes, the solution to your congruence, given the restriction on $x$, is $N\equiv 344\pmod {559}$.

Comment: @lulu this is why exponents multiple of 43 of ec primes could be related to this

Comment: I don't understand what that means.   Since the left hand of your congruence is just a constant , given the restriction on $x$, I really don't see what content there is in this.  But perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @lulu Isn't the residue modulo $41$ independent of the residue modulo $559$ ?

Comment: @lulu exponents of ec primes multiple of 86 are either of the form 23*34^x+5590y+588 or 223*34^x+5590y+588. I have not yet a proof that number of the form 223*34^X+5590Y+588 and numbers of the form 23*34^x+5590y+588 are either congruent to 0 or 344 mod 559

Comment: @lulu I forgot to say if 223*34^x+5590y+588 and 23*34^x+5590y+588 are multiple of 43

Comment: @Peter  I wasn't looking at the $\pmod {41}$ part.  For the $559$ bit we just get $344$ as a solution.  Any other congruences for $N$ could be handled by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.